# Text Array to Array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need convert from `data = "[[0,1], [1,1]]"` to `data = [[0,1], [1,1]]` in javascript, remove double quotes . It's possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `JSON` object:

```js
data = JSON.parse("[[0,1], [1,1]]"); // data === [[0,1], [1,1]]
```